# mysql prepared statement IFNULL

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I have this function which fetches "flightsize" out of a DB and uses it to setup an object.
I need to include a failsafe that, if there is no flightsize in the DB, makes flightsize = 6.
I read that i would want to use IFNULL for this, but unfortunally i cant get it to work.
Can someone assist me ?

In addition, would it be better to use IFNULL or create a new table entry for this "flight" to future selects will work ?

```
public function getFlightSize($gamedata){
    $stmt = $this->connection->prepare(
        "SELECT 
            shipid, flightsize
        FROM 
            tac_flightsize
        WHERE 
            gameid = ?"
        );

    if ($stmt){
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $gamedata->id);
        $stmt->bind_result($shipid, $flightsize);
        $stmt->execute();

        while($stmt->fetch()){
            $flight = $gamedata->getShipById($shipid);
            $flight->flightSize = $flightsize;
            $flight->populate();
        }

        $stmt->close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
        shipid, IFNULL(flightsize,6) AS flightsize
    FROM 
        tac_flightsize
    WHERE 
        gameid = ?
```

Should work, however if gameid is not present in your table, you will get no records at all in return and you will have to handle the situation in your php code.